# Converting a single shapefile with multiple features into independent GeoJSON files using ogr2ogr

Tags: gdal, shapefile, geojson, ogr2ogr, bash

Let's say there's a single shapefile that contains multiple features. Most of which are polygons.

How can one convert those features into separate independent GeoJSON files?

Can this be done with `ogr2ogr`?

Comment: Ogr2ogr writes out one dataset so you must select and convert the features one by one in a loop. Ogr2ogr options `-sql` or `-fid` can be used for selecting.

Comment: @user30184 So that would be like using `ogrinfo` to list the features and then loop them? Worth a shot though.

Comment: I think that in shapefile the FIDs run from 1 to the last so checking the number of features might be enough.

Comment: Upon doing the solution for this, I learned that FIDs are indexes. That means FIDs start from `0` and the last one is `count - 1`. I did exactly what you said, which is to select features one-by-one and in a loop.

Answer (score 2):

## TL;DR

```bsh
bash /path/to/shp2geojson.sh /path/to/input.shp /path/to/output-dir
```

#### `shp2geojson.sh`

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
clear;

layername=$(ogrinfo -nogeomtype "$1" | grep "1:" | awk '{print $2}')
count=$(ogrinfo -so -ro "$1" "$layername" | grep "Feature Count:" | awk '{print $3}')

if [ -d $2 ]; then
    echo "The directory $2 is now ready."
else
    mkdir "$2"
    echo "The directory $2 has just been created and now ready."
fi

for (( i=0; i<$count; i++ )); do
   echo "Processing feature #$i..."
   ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -t_srs EPSG:4326 -fid "$i" "$2/$i.geojson" "$1"
done
```

This bash script works for **Mac** and **Linux** machines. I do not know how to do it in batch script for *Windows*.

### Alternatively

If one wants to use a certain column from the attribute table (instead of the feature index) for the naming of the GeoJSON files, I have made [a derivative solution similar to the above script](https://gist.github.com/abelcallejo/882efec5356fb78820e912b20f8f48d6).